# Specific Days, Specific image on Front Page

Tags: images, scheduled-posts

Is there a plugin that will allow me to do the above?

Basically I have a webcomic that updates twice a week with two different stories. 
http://www.lunarblade.com
What I would like to be able to do is have it somehow automatically use image A for Tuesdays that'll tell people there's a new page of story A, and image B on Thursdays to show there's a new page of story B.

So if anyone knows a solution, via plugin or scripts (I'm a novice scripter of CSS), I would be very appreciative. I would love to find something that sets a specific image for a specific day.
Thank you for your time reading this!

Anat.

Comment: That's quite a specific request. FYI, plugins recommendation is [off-topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq), as well as pure CSS questions. I really doubt something like this exists as a plugin or as snippet somewhere in the interwebs *(CodeCanyon, maybe...)*. IMO, for anyone here to answer this would mean developing a full blown plugin. :::: I suggest you to reduce the scope (*edit the question*) to a code that swaps images in given days. After that, the kicker would be another question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have taken your advice and edited the question above. Let's see if perhaps anyone knows of a plugin that simply allows certain images to be associate with specific days!

Comment: Plugin recommendations are [off topic](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1217/73) here. We collect solutions, not links. :)

Answer (score 1):

Unless i missunderstood you,
This should be easy to do without using a plugin...

**Embed this in your functions.php:**

```
function echoDayImage() {
    // GET CURRENT DAY
    $currentDay = get_the_time('l');

    // CHECK DAY AND ECHO SUITABLE IMAGE
    if($currentDay = 'Sunday') {echo TEMPLATEPATH.'/images/Sunday.jpg';}
    elseif($currentDay = 'Monday') {echo TEMPLATEPATH.'/images/Monday.jpg';}
    elseif($currentDay = 'Tuesday') {echo TEMPLATEPATH.'/images/Tuesday.jpg';}
    elseif($currentDay = 'Wednesday') {echo TEMPLATEPATH.'/images/Wednesday.jpg';}
    elseif($currentDay = 'Thursday') {echo TEMPLATEPATH.'/images/Thursday.jpg';}
    elseif($currentDay = 'Friday') {echo TEMPLATEPATH.'/images/Friday.jpg';}
    elseif($currentDay = 'Saturday') {echo TEMPLATEPATH.'/images/Saturday.jpg';}
}
```

**Then in the location you wish to use it just use the function:**

```
<?php echoDayImage(); ?>
```

(learn more about formatting date / time here: [Customizing the Time and Date](http://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time))

**EDIT 1 (for comment explenation)**

```
function echoDayImage() {
    // GET CURRENT DAY
    $currentDay = get_the_time('l');
    echo TEMPLATEPATH.'/images/days/'.$currentDay;
}
```

Comment: +1 --> for this will work, hence is helpful to the OP and totally correct. That being said and done, allow me to say the following: 1. Why not simply use [`date('w')`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to grab the current day as an integer from 0 (Sunday) to 6? 2. In case you have never read them and are interested, you might want to take a look at the [WP Coding Standards](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Coding_Standards), camelCase isn't exactly common usage. Don't get me wrong, I don't mean to sneer at your answer, this is simply friendly advice. :)

Comment: thanks mate - i tried using days because... well if it was me i would skip the whole if - else and just get the image of the day using the returned value (see edit 1 in my answer)  but i wanted to make this answer readable... as for the string having a first capital letter see the first part of this explanation :) - in any case thanks for the tips & the input

Comment: Agreed, the edit is *much* simpler. If I wouldn't have upvoted this already, you'd have my upvote now.